# How do I tell my users' machines to authenticate against Azure

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm currently in the process of moving into a properly hybrid on-prem/Azure setup. I have a test group of machines that are registered as hybrid joined, I have my AD connector going to Azure AD for users and systems. And I have write back setup. So - if a user logs into their Office 365 account, they can change their password, and it's immediately reflected for their email and attached SSO services. However, if their machine is off premises, their new password will not work to log them into their system.

This, I know, is because the system is looking for the on-premise domain controller, but I'm at a loss as to where to begin with telling the systems to authenticate against Azure components. I've recently read Moskowitz's book on MDM, Intune, Azure, but I feel like I've missed something in that book that covers this very thing. Any help on this would be helpful, since I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

Answer (score 1):

Your machines need to be [Azure AD Joined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-join).

More detailed assessment and planning documents are provided at

[How to: Plan your Azure AD join implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/azureadjoin-plan)

Comment: Perhaps I used the wrong word for this. I wrote hybrid joined. I have several machines that are AAD joined as co-managed. Simply having them AAD joined does not allow for the machines to authenticate against Azure AD. There is some piece that is missing.